# Spacing of subscripts on subscripted variables that themselves appear in subscripts

Tags: spacing, subscripts

I'm trying to improve the spacing on and around the eta symbol that I typeset below. I use the symbol to denote elasticity (in economics). Eta will appear in expressions that can grow quite long, and eta will have different letters in the subscript, e.g. C, W, V, Y, etc.

My goal is to have clear but compact expressions. I have tried seven variations, see code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    % (1) letters in subscripts too large, subscripts not compact
    \hat{C}(\rho) &= \eta_{C(\rho) W(\rho)} \hat{W}(\rho)\\
    % 
    % (2) parentheses in subscript replaced by subscripts in subscript
    \hat{C}(\rho) &= \eta_{C_{\rho} W_{\rho}} \hat{W}(\rho)\\
    % 
    % (3) negative space added to rho in W-subscript in subscript
    \hat{C}(\rho) &= \eta_{C_{\rho} W_{\!\rho}} \hat{W}(\rho)\\
    % 
    % (4) subscript moved to subsubscript
    \hat{C}(\rho) &= \eta_{_{C_{\rho} W_{\!\rho}}} \hat{W}(\rho)\\
    % 
    % (5) negative thin space added between C and W in subscript
    \hat{C}(\rho) &= \eta_{_{C_{\rho}\!W_{\!\rho}}} \hat{W}(\rho)\\
    % 
    % (6) mathit added for more even placement of rho on C and W in subscript
    \hat{C}(\rho) &= \eta_{_{\mathit{C_{\rho}\!W_{\!\rho}}}} \hat{W}(\rho)\\
    % 
    % mathop added for better spacing between eta and functions C(rho) and W(rho)
    \mathop{\hat{C}}(\rho) &= \eta_{_{\mathit{C_{\rho}\!W_{\!\rho}}}} \mathop{\hat{W}}(\rho)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I like option seven, but I have some questions:

1. Have I violated any typesetting style rules that will jump out at (and bother) well-trained eyes?
2. Have I missed some tricks or best practices that will improve my typesetting, particularly around spacing, but also around other aspects of mathematical typesetting?
3. Have I missed an obvious alternative option for typesetting variables with information-rich subscripts?

Thank you for your advice!

[image]

Comment: And what if you want `T_{C_{\rho}}` in the same formula? If you do differently because it is a T and not an eta, it will look strange. If you make the subscript smaller (by the double `_`) it will look strange. I would simply go with (1) (and perhaps change notation if it was bothering me too much).

Comment: Good point about other symbols, such as T, appearing with subscripts alongside eta---that would indeed look strange. Option (1) was my first inclination, as it seems to be yours, but then I got to typesetting some of the longer expressions in my paper, and the sheer number of repeated symbols with parentheses started to look quite unappealing, so I switched to the subscripted variables in subscripts, and then I thought, why not go further and double subscript to reduce size. Your comment has me leaning back towards option (1), thank you very much for sharing your thoughts on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oberve that neither `{\eta_C}_{\rho}` nor `\eta_{C_{\rho}}` throw a sytax error and are therefore "correct" from a purely TeX-syntax point of view. Which alternative is correct *in terms of content* depends entirely on whether (a) `\rho` indexes `\eta_C` or (b) `C_{\rho}` indexes `\eta`. My impression is that it's the latter. If this impression is correct, do write `\eta_{C_{\rho}}` and `\eta_{C_{\rho}W_{\rho}}`.

I can see no justification for `\eta_{_{C_{\rho} W_{\!\rho}}}` or `\eta_{_{C_{\rho}\!W_{\!\rho}}}`.

If you prefer to shift the subscripts down a bit, do replace `\eta_{C_{\rho}}` with `\eta^{}_{C_{\rho}}`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Mico, I will adopt the suggestion to add ^{} to shift the subscripts down, it helps. My justification for the double-subscript was only that the single-subscripts appear quite large, in particular on `\eta`. Generally, an `\eta` with subscript `\eta_{X(\rho)Y(\rho)}` will consistently multiply `Y(\rho)`, and in many expressions there are many `\eta`'s with such subscripts, and as the expressions grow in length, it can be difficult to distinguish at a glance between subscript and variable multiplied by `\eta`. But your point is well taken, single subscripts may be better.